# Accessing Vimeo API via access script using the vimeo ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, vimeo, vimeo-api

I would like to grab the thumbnail urls of a list of restricted videos.

I created an app with vimeo and got an access token.

How do I use this access token to gain access to the method? When I try this:

```
videos = Vimeo::Advanced::Video.new("client_identifier", "client_secret", 
    :token => "access_token")
videos.get_thumbnail_urls(the_video_id)
```

I get

```
Vimeo::Advanced::RequestFailed: 401: Permission Denied, explanation: The oauth_token passed was either not valid or has expired.
```

My users don't have vimeo accounts so I don't see the point (or a way) have them authenticate with vimeo. I would like to grab the thumbnails of videos uploaded by the same account which created the app. My understanding is that the access token I generated ought to provide this access.

What am I missing?

**Update: Here's what worked for me, based on the accepted answer**

```
require 'httparty'

video_id = "123456789"   # substitute with the desired video ID
api_url = "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/#{video_id}/"  
auth = "Bearer access_token_generated_by_vimeo"    # use your access token
r = HTTParty.get api_url, headers: { "Authorization" => auth, "Accept" => "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.2" }  # make sure to use the proper Accept header as recommended in the API docs
v = JSON.parse(r)
v["pictures"]["sizes"][1]["link"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Advanced API is Vimeo's old API. This has been deprecated, and many of the libraries still only work with this old API.

Luckily the new API is very easy and you don't really need a library. Particularly if all you want is thumbnail access.

**Authentication**

Take a look at the docs for Single vs. Multi user applications on the [dev site](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#getting-started). Since your users don't have vimeo accounts you should follow the instructions for a single user account (basically hard code a single access token. You can generate this token on your app page under the "Authentication" tab".

**API Requests**

The new [API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api) uses a much cleaner authentication and request structure. Thumbnails are provided alongside all video responses. This includes [https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D), [https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/me/videos), [https://api.vimeo.com/channels/{channel_id}/videos](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/channels/%7Bchannel_id%7D/videos) and more.

Vimeo recommends you include your access token in a header (Authorization: bearer {token}) but the system does allow you to provide it through the URL (?access_token={token}).

A final request could look like

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos
Authorization: bearer abcd1234
```

**Ruby**

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with ruby, so I can't help with translating this to ruby, but there's likely a great HTTP library out there that can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. The ruby gem uses the old API and I was getting confused between the gem docs and the vimeo docs.

Comment: [jsonResultDic setObject:@"456a8852ebd72760de4d2206bab3dad0db35a66b" forKey:@"client_id"];//@"consumer_key"
[jsonResultDic setObject:@"eb74abb5d1f38ad0bd570d24e4d1d0ee3a447534" forKey:@"client_secret"];//@"consumer_secret"
[jsonResultDic setObject:@"vimeo.channels.getAll" forKey:@"method"];[jsonResultDic setObject:@"bearer a75a63c0e0121b0704a4c98d6e209eb2" forKey:@"Authorization"];

Comment: NSString *urlPost = @"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2";ASIHTTPRequest  *request1 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPost]];NSString* str=[jsonResultDic JSONRepresentation];NSData *jsonData =[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];[request1 setRequestMethod:@"GET"];[request1 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPost]];[request1 setPostBody:(NSMutableData*)jsonData];[request1 addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:@"bearer a75a63c0e0121b0704a4c98d6e209eb2"];[request1 addRequestHeader:@"client_id" value:@"456a8852ebd72760de4d2206bab3dad0db35a66b"];

Comment: [request1 addRequestHeader:@"client_secret" value:@"eb74abb5d1f38ad0bd570d24e4d1d0ee3a447534"];[request1 setCompletionBlock:^{}];[request1 setFailedBlock:^{}];[request1 startSynchronous];

Comment: Hi, Here is my code in ios. I am sending token, but it "The consumer key passed was not valid"

Comment: "vimeo.com/api/rest/v2" is the url for the old API. The URLs I provided in the answer above are the correct urls (api.vimeo.com)

Comment: @Dashron I have same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238569/how-to-make-api-request-to-get-private-vimeo-videos-in-objective-c) with Vimeo API. please help me.

Comment: Which issue? It might be best to contact us at vimeo.com/help/contact

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me to get a video id from a query string after much experimentation (with thanks to all the above posters).

```
escaped_title = CGI::escape(title)
api_url = "https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=#{escaped_title}&sort=relevant&access_token=#{@access_token}"
vimeo_response = JSON.parse(HTTParty.get api_url)
vimeo_id = vimeo_response["data"][0]["uri"]
```