# How to make API request to get private Vimeo videos in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, get, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-ios

I'm developing an iOS application to play private Vimeo videos. Private videos are given privacy of hiding videos from Vimeo website and given domains so that those videos only will be bought and played in my websites. I have Vimeo PRO account.

I am using VIMNetworking SDK and make authentication in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() by using client details I got creating app at https://developer.vimeo.com/apps.

Now I have to make API request to get direct video urls. I don't know how to achieve this. Vimeo doesn't give documentation for objective-c. By using below code I get public video response but not working for private videos.

```
 [[VIMSession sharedSession].client requestURI:@"/videos/4378389" completionBlock:^(VIMServerResponse *response, NSError *error) {        
        id JSONObject = response.result;
        NSLog(@"JSONObject: %@", JSONObject);
    }];
```

I even tried this code to get private videos. But I get  in response.

```
 VIMClient *client = [[VIMClient alloc] initWithDefaultBaseURL];

    client.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [client.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/vnd.vimeo.*+json; version=3.2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
     [client.requestSerializer setValue:@"my_client_id" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


    [client requestURI:@"https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos" completionBlock:^(VIMServerResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {

        id JSONObject = response.result;
        NSLog(@"JSONObject: %@", JSONObject);

    }];
```

And there's the third way with getting these errors: "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" and "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/vnd.vimeo.error+json". Its a long error description.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSDictionary *param = @{@"response_type" : @"code", @"client_id" : @"my_cleint_id", @"redirect_uri" : @"vimeo{my_cleint_id}://auth", @"state" : @"exercise"};

[manager GET:@"https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos" parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {

     NSLog(@"Forgot Password JSON: %@",responseObject);


 }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);

      }];
```

Is it something with access_token that I need to pass? if yes then how to get this access_token? I'm so stuck here. Your little help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you passing a "client ID" or an actual OAuth token? You will need to sign your requests with the latter.

Comment: @AlfieHanssen actually, now I'm able to get private video urls using Vimeo SDK. This SDK perform all of the code I wrote in question. I just need to pass client id. The problem is that user must have to go to Vimeo login page to log in and allow my app to access Vimeo videos. Is there any way I can skip it?

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo implements OAuth 2.0 Bearer Tokens. You should use it like this:

```
[serializer setValue:@"Bearer your_token_here" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

It is described in details [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re)